# I've registered categories for Wordpress attachments but categories appear empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a website about dogs with a lot of images. Users should be able to find images based on categories (name of dog breed, for example). Thus I need the website to treat attachments like regular blog posts and list them under categories, in the form of a post, like below:

[image: image wrapped in post]

For this purpose, I registered categories and tags for attachments, using the code below in functions.php :

```
// add categories for attachments

function add_categories_for_attachments() {
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
} 

add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_for_attachments' ); 


// add tags for attachments

function add_tags_for_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}

add_action( 'init' , 'add_tags_for_attachments' );
```

Now Media really show categories and tags, like below:

[image: Media categories]

However the category page does not retrieve anything. For example, although I have at least three images/attachments under the category Beagle, when trying to view the Beagle category nothing appears. It is being considered an empty category, although three attachments have it.

[image]

I suppose it is because the query by category is being performed just among regular posts and not including attachments. I've been searching about this for days, but have not found out how to include attachments in category queries, so that my attachment categories do not appear empty. Please help! :P

Answer (score 1):

Sharing what I found out, in case someone else should ever need the same answer...

There are actually two issues here: one related to the "main query" and the other related to "category counter".

1) To include attachments in the main query (and thus retrieve attachments together with regular posts, when viewing a category), one could add the following filter to functions.php:

```
function my_custom_filter($query) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( $query->is_archive() ) {
            $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
            $query->set('post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_custom_filter');
```

2) To have attachments populate categories so that they no longer appear empty, I created a work around. I suppose it is not the most elegant and wise solution, but it does work. Perform the following mySQL query in your WordPress SQL database:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status`='publish' WHERE `post_type`='attachment' AND `post_status`='inherit' AND `post_mime_type`='image/jpeg'
```

Attachments do not normally appear in categories because their default post_status is "inherit". This query changes it to "publish", just like a regular post.

WordPress codex mentions that:

> Because an attachment is a type of post, the default
>   _update_post_term_count() will be used (in the register_taxonomy() function). However, this may be undesirable, because this will only
>   count attachments that are actually attached to another post (like
>   when you insert an image into a post). This means that attachments
>   that you simply upload to WordPress using the Media Library, but do
>   not actually attach to another post will not be counted. (...) You
>   should force the use of _update_generic_term_count() by setting
>   '_update_generic_term_count' as the value for update_count_callback.
>   Another important consideration is that _update_post_term_count() only
>   counts published posts. If you are using custom statuses, or using
>   custom post types where being published is not necessarily a
>   consideration for being counted in the term count, then you will need
>   to provide your own callback that doesn't include the post_status
>   portion of the where clause.

This surely would be the proper solution for the counter issue but I did not find enough information to allow me to implement it. I was unable to figure out how to force '_update_generic_term_count' over categories without having categories overwritten by a new call to register_taxonomy(), which would delete all the current configuration of categories. And I found absolutely no info  about "providing my own callback that doesn't include the post_status". What would be the proper syntax for this callback function? Where should I include it? Should anyone know it, please share it.